# get rows grouped by just when state changed to opposite values from previous

Tags: mysql

I have table:

```
ID  STATUS
----------
0   0
1   1
2   0
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   0
7   3
8   2
9   0
10  1 etc.
```

I want to get only first occurences of 1 and 2 when they change state (I mean 0 and 3 are not important to me) - so in this case I should get ids: 1, 4, 10. I tried group by but it only groups all values by 1 or 2, and not just the cases when states has changed.
Any idea please how to specify mysql query?

Comment: If 0 is unimportant to you why do you get 1 and 10 in your result?

Comment: I am getting it beacause it should return "starting" and 'changing" points of 1 and 2 - where they are switching between them, but additional 1-2 values after value has been once changed should be ommited.

Comment: You can use subqueries

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What about `ID=3`?

Answer (score 0):

So, it's a slow day...

```
SELECT MIN(id)
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , CASE WHEN @prev=status THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=status prev 
         FROM 
            ( SELECT * 
                FROM my_table 
               WHERE status IN (1,2)
            ) x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=1,@i:=1 ) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY id
     ) a
 GROUP
   BY i;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
     , status
     , if( status = @switch
          and if( @switch = 1, @switch:=2, @switch:=1 ) in(1,2)
         , 1
         , 0
         ) sw 
  FROM status
    JOIN( SELECT @switch :=1 ) t
  WHERE status in (1,2)
  HAVING sw=1
  ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Code only answers are not of a great quality, you should explain how this query solves the question.